# In React how can I get access to the props before rendering (without using componentWillReceiveProps)

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which renders based on data which is transformed from the properties. Specifically, one of the properties for the component is straight out JSON. That JSON is then transformed by the component into the actual data used in the rendering.

So this is the bit I dont get. If I updated my props then the render function gets called before I have the opportunity to transform into the data for rendering. I discovered the componentWillReceiveProps function which works perfectly, I can prepare my data prior to the rendering.

However I am seeing that this is now being deprecated and the other suggestions seem to be deficient in their own ways (either called after render, or not called on mount etc)

I dont think my use case seems particularly unique, or maybe seeing as I am knew to React I am misunderstaning the usage of props, but if not then why does this not seem to be supported?

What options do I have to update my component with new data and have that data transformed prior to the render occuring?

For clarity this is what i am doing. And the **props.data** is the property that is transformed by the component ideally prior to rendering.

```
    let props: IComponentProps = {
        data: context.parameters.json.raw != null ? JSON.parse(context.parameters.json.raw) : undefined,
        node:  context.parameters.node.raw || undefined,
        callback: (x) => console.log(`Got a callback on ${x}`)};

    ReactDOM.render(<FluentUIDetailsListControl {...props} />, container);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
}
```

this function triggered before the render function in the creation cycle and triggered firstly after each update.

The props variable is the passed props.

Mainly you used props to set the state.